# How Can I Set Dictionary Value On Other Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a C# beginner, I've encountered a problem as below, but I'm not sure what is causing it or how to fix it. Experience coders, please help.

I have a `Dictionary` in Form1, but I want to set its value from Form2. However, after assigning the value, the `MessageBox` result still shows 0;

Form1: msgbox show result = 0

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bidcoords["TEST"] = 0;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> bidcoords = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(bidcoords["TEST"].Value.ToString());
    }
```

Form2:

```
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       form1.bidcoords["TEST"] = 30; 
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Your are creating brand new object of Form1. Instead of this you need to pass existing instance of form1 to from2. But I advice you to pass only dictionary object instead of form

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> Bidcoords {get; set;}

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Bidcoords != null && Bidcoords.ContainsKey("TEST"))
           Bidcoords["TEST"] = 30;
    }
}

public class Form1: Form
{
    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2{Bidcoords = bidcoords ;}
        form.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(bidcoords["TEST"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't put new Form1(), i received NullrefernceException ? Can you show me quick solution that i can set Dictionary value on Form2

Answer (score 4):

At some point in your program you are creating `Form2` and showing it.  At that point in time you are **in `Form1`**.  That `Form1`, the same one you can see on the screen, is the form you are trying to update.  If you try to create another `Form1` using `new`, all you will have is two `Form1` instances, which is not what you want.

You need to communicate between `Form1` and `Form2` that instance of `Form1`.

There are two common approaches to doing this:

1. Add a property called `MainForm` to `Form2`. After you create `Form2`, set `form2.MainForm = this;`
2. Add a constructor to `Form2` that takes a `Form` as an argument and save that away

In either case, then when you are in `Form2`, use that variable to set the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need one common dictionnay you should declare it as a singleton

```
public class DictionarySingleton
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, int> Instance = new Dictionary<string, int>();
}
```

so you can access it from both form and even have several forms instance of the same class changing the same dictionary, like said in the previous posts, you are creating another instance of Form1 and thus another instance of your dictionary.

to access your dictionary from anywhere :

```
DictionarySingleton.Instance["foo"]=0;
```