# Connection between 2 forms

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I'm creating and adding objects to dictionary in first form. 
I want to search it in second form, because I want to draw signs on the panel depending on objects created in the first form.

I saw this 
[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166400/how-can-i-set-dictionary-value-on-other-form) but I don't know, how I have to add a constructor to Form2 which takes a Form as an argument ?

I was trying to make singleton dictionary, but also I don't know how get to values from dictionary in foreach loop.

When everyting would be in this same form I should make this by: luskanie.value.rodzaj, if i have two forms this doesnt work.

Code from form1 dictionary:

```
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public static Dictionary<int, baza> naszalista = new Dictionary<int, baza>(); 


This is second form:


    namespace _1dwa3
    {
        public partial class diagram : Form
        {

        public diagram()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void diagram_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush laczniki = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
            Pen lacznikipen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 5);
            SolidBrush funkcja = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            Pen funkcjapen = new Pen(Color.Green, 5);
            SolidBrush zdarzenie = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Pen zdarzeniepen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
            SolidBrush strzalka = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            Graphics rysujem = panel1.CreateGraphics();


            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, baza> luskanie in Form1.naszalista)
            {

                if (baza.rodzaj == "funkcja")
                {
                    rysujem.FillEllipse(funkcja,20,20,40,20);
                    rysujem.DrawString(funkcjazdarzenie.opis, new Font("Segoe", 9), Brushes.Green, 20, 20);
                }
                else if (baza.rodzaj == "zdarzenie")
                {
                    rysujem.FillPie(zdarzenie,20,20,20,20,20,20);
                }
                else if (baza.rodzaj == "XOR")
                {

                }
                else if (baza.rodzaj == "OR")
                {

                }
                else if (baza.rodzaj == "AND")
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thx for any advice, I was trying to make this question specific.

I'm adding here, also classes with shortly description

```
public class baza    /* this is superior class, it contains rodzaj = which give me opportunity, to know which shape shold be printed, idpoprzedniego give me chance to know after which shape it should be printed */
{
  public  string rodzaj;
  public  int idpoprzedniego;

}
```

Now the class which inheritance from baza, it have a contructor and have new string opis = which contain text describing action. For example " The boss need to sign documents"

```
public class funkcjazdarzenie : baza //          
{
  public string opis;
  public funkcjazdarzenie(string krodzaj, string kopis, int kidpoprzedniego)
    {
        rodzaj = krodzaj;
        idpoprzedniego = kidpoprzedniego;
        opis = kopis;
    }

}
```

Xor/Or/and have this same sign on the illustration it will be circle, but the differences between them will be in the text in the middle of the shape, like the names of classes it would be xor/or/and

```
public class xor : baza //klasa odpowiedzialna za xora 
{
    public xor(string krodzaj,int kidpoprzedniego)
    {
        rodzaj = krodzaj;
        idpoprzedniego = kidpoprzedniego;
    }


}

public class or : baza //klasa odpowiedzialna za ora 
{
    public or(string krodzaj,int kidpoprzedniego)
    {
        rodzaj = krodzaj;
        idpoprzedniego = kidpoprzedniego;
    }

}

public class and : baza // klasa odpowiedzialna za and 
{
    public and(string krodzaj,int kidpoprzedniego)
    {
        rodzaj = krodzaj;
        idpoprzedniego = kidpoprzedniego;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made a reference to the other form and then call that form?

Comment: You should seriously consider reading about some 'coding conventions'. I suggest You start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx).

Comment: Are you going to use MDI forms? If you you should actually have one form only, and use UserControls types instead.

Comment: @GrzegorzW I'm going to read this before bedtime, because I think it would be helpful in future ;)

Comment: @Marco Thx, I look what it is. Maybe I will made it in this application.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13324/Adding-MDI-Support-to-Windows-Forms-Applications-N, a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made the Dictionary in Form1 static, and are accessing it correctly from Form2.  The problem is in your For loop.  The "luskanie" variable represents a KeyValuePair so you should be using it to access the "rodzaj" member.

So instead of:

```
if (baza.rodzaj == "funkcja")
```

You should have:

```
if (luskanie.Value.rodzaj == "funkcja")
```

All together, you could make it look something like:

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush laczniki = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        Pen lacznikipen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 5);
        SolidBrush funkcja = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        Pen funkcjapen = new Pen(Color.Green, 5);
        SolidBrush zdarzenie = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Pen zdarzeniepen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
        SolidBrush strzalka = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Graphics rysujem = panel1.CreateGraphics();


        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, baza> luskanie in Form1.naszalista)
        {
            baza bz = luskanie.Value;

            if (bz.rodzaj == "funkcja")
            {
                rysujem.FillEllipse(funkcja, 20, 20, 40, 20);
                rysujem.DrawString(funkcjazdarzenie.nazwa, new Font("Segoe", 9), Brushes.Green, 20, 20);
            }
            else if (bz.rodzaj == "zdarzenie")
            {
                rysujem.FillPie(zdarzenie, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20);
            }
            else if (bz.rodzaj == "XOR")
            {

            }
            else if (bz.rodzaj == "OR")
            {

            }
            else if (bz.rodzaj == "AND")
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx for answer and clearly explanation. Yeah something with loop was done in wrong way, but now I have Error i this row                 if (bz.rodzaj == "funkcja")                      '_1dwa3.baza.rodzaj' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: So you've marked "rodzaj" as static, which means it has the **same** value across all instances, but your use of a Dictionary() suggests you want to associate **different** values of it based on the integer key.  Remove the static keyword.  If that doesn't make sense then you'll need to explain in more detail about the design of the classes and how they relate to your drawing.

Comment: On the bottom of this comment I will add my classes with shortly description. Yeah I want to take from dictionary the value which describing a object.For example user choosing the funkcja object giving the description " the documents are in office" and pressing button go to chart, on the second form we should see the Ellipse with the text in the middle "the documents are in office".Now I haven't got any errors but I can't take the string nazwa, because it isn't in the class baza, but in the class "funkcjazdzarzenie" which inheritance from baza.

Comment: I add classes on the bottom of question, If Something is not clearly described pliz say it. When i want to put objects from various classes and the only thing which link them is the inheritance from baza. The dictionary should be type of baza as I have in my application?

Comment: Yes, the value type for the Dictionary can be of type baza.  You can check the TYPE of the value and CAST it to the derived types as necessary.  With the additional classes you posted, "if (bz.rodzaj == "funkcja")" should not be giving the error you provided.  There's a disconnect between what you're posting and what you actually have in your project.

Comment: "if (bz.rodzaj == "funkcja")"  this line is absolutely correct.       I have problem with taking the "opis" string, which is in the class "funkcjazdarzenie". This class is connected by inheritance with baza class.                                                              To be specific this line: "rysujem.DrawString(funkcjazdarzenie.opis, new Font("Segoe", 9), Brushes.Green, 20, 20);
            }"

Comment: OK...that's why I mentioned checking the TYPE of the class so you can CAST it.  For example: `if (bz is funkcjazdarzenie) { funkcjazdarzenie F = (funkcjazdarzenie)bz; // ...now do something with "F"...like access "opis"... }`

Comment: thx, so much for all information ;) I see now, how much i have to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

For sending values between two forms, you may

1. Send the values in the constructor of the second form. You may create a paramterized constructor and send the values when you initialize the form.
2. You may take a reference in to your first form in the second form as:

In second form,

```
public Form1 objForm1;
```

and in First Form,

```
Form2 objForm2=new Form2();
Form2.objForm1=this;
```

and then you can use Form2's objForm1 to refer to Form1's dictionary items as

```
//Form1.Dict_Name=values;
```